# What is an homotopy group in a model category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

> What is the notion, if any, of which all the known homotopy groups are particular cases?

Let me elaborate on this.

Given a model category $\cal M$ one can define a notion of homotopy group with $A$ coefficients posing, say,
$$
\pi_n^A(X) = [A, \Omega^n X]
$$
if $A$ is cofibrant (if not, just take a replacement $QA$).

$X\mapsto \Omega X$ is of course the homotopy fiber of a pointed object.

A natural choice for such an $A$, available in any $\cal M$, is $S^0 := *\coprod *$. And it is a fact that in this way you obtain a "model for spheres" in $\cal M$, because you can inductively define
$$
\begin{gather}
\big( S^{n-1} \xrightarrow{cof} D^n \xrightarrow{wfib} * \big)\leadsto D^n \\
S^n = D^n/S^{n-1}
\end{gather}
$$
etc. But then, how do these groups behave? One would naively expect that this definition, or a tightly related one, gives rise to

- homotopy groups of topological spaces
- rational homotopy groups
- homotopy groups with coefficients, *à la* Neisendorfer
- homotopy groups of chain complexes, that people in '900 used to call "singular homology groups"
- homotopy groups of spectra
- homotopy groups of sheaves
- ...

Now, it is unlikely that all these notions stem from a single *ur-homotopy object*, and yet I can't see *why* they don't.¹

So:

> why they don't?

I'm looking for a balance in the kind of answer I want, here: on one side, I don't want to see via an example **that** they don't. I want to know **why** they don't. But then I also would like the answer to be concrete enough to let me say "aha! That's why!".

> Whatever the issue is with those "naive" $\pi_n(-)$, can it be solved? You maybe don't want $S^0$ to be generated by the terminal object, but instead by a generator (of the category): in the end this is what happens in chain complexes and spaces. Is it the right track?²

---

¹: An on-the-fly counterexample is that in chain complexes you don't want to define $S^0$ that way, but instead as the singular complex of $S^0$ (and then you get al spheres by shifting). Also, it seems that wrt the folk model structure on $\bf Cat$, the $\Omega$ functor sends a group $G$ into its action groupoid, so that $\text{Ho}({\bf Cat})(\{*,*\}, \Omega G)$ is trivial as soon as $G$ is, say, abelian.

²  Or maybe you want to choose your coefficients in a smarter way. Or maybe in general *you can't* hope to have nice coefficients since the definition above depends on the model structure, and if it is too simple...

Comment: Surely in all of these examples one can define the homotopy groups of $X$ as the homotopy groups of a topological space, the ''derived function space`` $Map(A,X)$ for some object $A$. Depending on what $\mathcal M$ is, there may be one or many interesting/useful choices of what $A$ should be, or none at all.

Comment: If ${\cal M}$ is a (say pointed) monoidal model category then there is essentially no loss of generality in taking $A$ to be the unit because $Map(A,B) \simeq Map(1_{{\cal M}},B^A)$, where $B^A$ is the associated cotensor structure. There are also many interesting cases in which the corepresented homotopy groups are not that useful but a certain enriched version is. For example, to a (suitably pointed) sheaf of spaces one can associate a homotopy **sheaf** of groups. For profinite spaces, one has profinite homotopy groups.

Comment: If your category has a zero object, your definition of $S^0$ will just give the zero object. In a monoidal setting, consider using the tensor unit in place of the terminal object. Supplement with everything in the (up-to-homotopy) Picard group -- e.g. in motivic homotopy theory one has bigraded homotopy groups coming from $\wedge$'s of two $\wedge$-invertible objects. Or maybe what's really going on is that as soon as you start studying some kind of "homotopy group" you immediately think about "stabilizing" to _force_ the object representing the homotopy group into the Picard group...

Comment: When the model category is left proper and cofibrantly generated, the homotopy groups of all $map(A,X)$ for $A$ running over the set of domains and codomains of the generating cofibrations enable to characterize the weak equivalences (see Proposition 3.2 of http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(00)00172-9).